# immutable of type only has mutating members

Tags: swift

Following code is throwing an error "Immutable value of type [User] only has mutating members named append" please advise.

**Library or Framework code (precompiled)**

```
class Database {
    var data: Any? //can change this code but has to be a generic placeholder

    init(data: Any?=nil) {
        self.data = data
    }
}
```

**Users of the Library or Framework code**

```
class User {
    var first: String
    var last: String

    init(first: String, last:String) {
        self.first = first
        self.last = last
    }
}

class Test: Database {

    init() {
        super.init(data: [User]())
    }

    func addItem(item: User) { //edit User type from Any but problem persists
        (self.data as! [User]).append(item) //error
    }
}
```

**Attempt 1**, this seems to be working but still wonder why above code doesn't work.

```
func addItem(item: User) {
    var users = self.data as! [User]
    users.append(item);
    self.data = users; 
}
```

**don't like the re-assignment, how can in place mutability be possible**

Comment: the issue is that you are trying to add an object of type `Any` in an array of `User`, try using `item as User`

Comment: still have the same problem, I've both pieces of code (library + my code) in playground for testing

Comment: data is of type Any. This is not an array. So you can't use append.

Comment: @ThomasKilian I've provided `[User]()` to the `data: Any`, also there's a force cast down in `addItem`, Any suggestion to change the Library code (it has to be generic, supposed to hold all kinds of variables)

Answer (score 1):

I've written an (what I believe to be) elegant solution for this problem.

```
public struct Accessor<T, U>
{
    public let (getter: (T -> U), setter: (U -> T))

    public init()
    {
        (getter, setter) = ({ $0 as! U }, { $0 as! T })
    }

    public init(_ getter: (T -> U), _ setter: (U -> T))
    {
        self.getter = getter
        self.setter = setter
    }
}

extension Accessor: NilLiteralConvertible
{
    public init(nilLiteral: ())
    {
        self.init()
    }
}

public class Mediator<T, U>
{
    public var rawValue: UnsafeMutablePointer<T>
    public var accessor: Accessor<T, U>

    public init(_ rawValue: UnsafeMutablePointer<T>, _ accessor: Accessor<T, U> = nil)
    {
        self.rawValue = rawValue
        self.accessor = Accessor<T, U>({ $0 as! U }, { $0 as! T })
    }

    public var value: U
    {
        get
        {
            return accessor.getter(rawValue.memory)
        }

        set
        {
            rawValue.memory = accessor.setter(newValue)
        }
    }
}
```

Which allows for:

```
Mediator<Any?, [User]>(&self.data).value.append(item)
```

Comment: I appreciate your attempt but it's too advanced or complex for this assignment, I need a simple solution

Comment: Your attempt is the simplest it gets.

Comment: any explanation of why the above code didn't work for me for the sake of understanding

Comment: When you cast to a value type, the result is always immutable.